# how to pass a generic method to a static function

Tags: c++, std

i need to call a member function on every element of a vector stored as a static member in the class itself.

to do this with ptfs i should write a lot of code, but i am quite sure there is a `<functional>` mechanism than can help me on this.

language is c++03 (vs2010)

example:

```
class C
{
    static std::vector<C*> pool;

    void a(){}
    void b(){}
    void c(){}

    static void Call( anymethod am )
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(int)pool.size();i++)
        {
            pool[i]->am();
        }
    }
}`
std::vector<C*> C::pool;
```

Comment: There's something missing from your question. That would be an actual, specific question.

Comment: Off topic: rather than casting the size to an `int` and risking an overflow in the loop, use a more suitable type for the index. `size_t` should do it for you.

Comment: If you always want to call a member function of the class C, then a pointer to a member function would work.

Comment: You should consider upgrading your compiler. Given that VS 2010 is based on C++ 98/03, it is quite solete for C++ development.

Comment: @Phil1970     newer c++ are java, i don't like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pointer-to-member-function, which is part of the language (don't need `<functional>`):

```
void Call(void (C::*am)()) {
    for (std::vector<C*>::size_type i = 0; i < pool.size(); i++) {
        (pool[i]->*am)();
    }
}

Call(&C::a);
```

However, the usual thing to do (pre-C++11) is to accept a functor - which is to say, an object with an `operator()`. There are some built into `<functional>`.

```
template<class F>
void Call(F am) {
    for (std::vector<C*>::size_type i = 0; i < pool.size(); i++) {
        am(pool[i]);
    }
}

Call(std::mem_fun(&C::a));
```

There is an utility method in `<algorithm>` that does precisely this traversal over an iterator range with a functor.

```
template<class F>
void Call(F am) {
    std::for_each(pool.begin(), pool.end(), am);
}
```

Comment: My error was to not parenthesize the final expression, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had done something similar to what you wanted to do a couple weeks ago.  What I would up using was `std::placeholders::_1` for the `&instance` parameter when binding member functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders

Basically, member functions quietly pass a 'this' pointer to the function that you normally use `std::bind` to bind.  I tried using the _1 placeholder instead and then called `f(&instance)` and it worked.

However, I switched tack and took a different approach:

```
#include <functional>
class C
{
    static std::vector<C*> pool;

    void a(){}
    void b(){}
    void c(){}

    static void Call( const std::function<void(C*)>& func )
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(int)pool.size();i++)
        {
            func(pool[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And passed a function that called a specific member function:

```
Call( [=](C* obj){
    obj->am();  // change this to whatever member function you want to call
} );
```

I use MSVC2010 for this